# timecode of scene change detection ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Good day, there was a bit of a problem when I working with ffmpeg. We need to find timecodes of scene change detection in the video. Use the following command:

ffmpeg -i inputVideo.mp4 -f image2 -vf "select = gt (scene \ ,. 5)" -vsync vfr thumb% 04d.png

It creates an image from scene change detection. I do not know how to add timecode to a text file. Thanks in advance for your help!)

P.S. Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use `ffprobe` with the [Libavfilter input virtual device (lavfi)](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#lavfi).

You can do this to list the timestamps in the console:

```sh
ffprobe -show_frames -print_format compact -f lavfi \
"movie=test.mp4,select=gt(scene\,.8)" | egrep -o "pkt_pts_time=[0-9.]+"
```

where `.8` is the scene detection threshold.

The `-print_format` also supports CSV, JSON, XML which makes it easier to import the data in other programs.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the command:

```
ffmpeg inputvideo.mp4 -filter_complex "select='gt(scene,0.3)',metadata=print:file=time.txt" -vsync vfr img%03d.png
```

This will save just the relevant information in the time.txt file like below:

```
frame:0    pts:108859  pts_time:1.20954
lavfi.scene_score=0.436456
frame:1    pts:285285  pts_time:3.16983
lavfi.scene_score=0.444537
frame:2    pts:487987  pts_time:5.42208
lavfi.scene_score=0.494256
frame:3    pts:904654  pts_time:10.0517
lavfi.scene_score=0.462327
frame:4    pts:2533781 pts_time:28.1531
lavfi.scene_score=0.460413
frame:5    pts:2668916 pts_time:29.6546
lavfi.scene_score=0.432326
```

The frame is the serial number of the detected shot change from the starting. Also, choose your threshold value (here 0.3) appropriately for your use case to get correct outputs